# AngularJs ngResource factory. Var returning function instead of promise

Tags: angularjs, ngresource

I am writing a factory in angular that uses two sets of data. I need one set of data to equal a variable so I can pass that in another API call. For some reason my variable always returns the whole function instead of just returning the variables. All environment variables are available.

```
var zones = function(){
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            $resource(ENV.web_api_url + ENV.api_version + '/zones/:zoneId', {}, {
                query: {
                    method: 'GET',
                    cache: false,
                    params: {zoneId: '@zoneId', date: $filter('date')(new Date(), "yyyy-MM-dd")},
                    isArray: true,
                    headers: {
                        "X-Auth-Token": $window.sessionStorage.token
                    }
                }
            }).success(function(data){
                deferred.resolve(data);
            }).error(function(){
                deferred.reject('There was an error')
            });
            return deferred.promise;
        };
```

Answer (score 1):

you do not need your own promise to use ng-resource:

```
var zones = function(){
return $resource(query : {...}).query();
}
```

Comment: If I do this it returns nothing

Answer (score 0):

You define a resource and call ".success()" on the actual resource instead on invoking GET. Here is what you should do:

```
var res = $resource(ENV.web_api_url + ENV.api_version + '/zones/:zoneId', {}, {
            query: {
                method: 'GET',
                cache: false,
                params: {zoneId: '@zoneId', date: $filter('date')(new               Date(), "yyyy-MM-dd")},
                isArray: true,
                headers: {
                    "X-Auth-Token": $window.sessionStorage.token
                }
            }
        });
        res.get(null, function(data){
            deferred.resolve(data);
        },function(){
            deferred.reject('There was an error')
        });
```

Comment: I just edited the syntax there. You should definitely read that page though: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource